# jQuery toggle menu with counting elements.

Tags: jquery, menu, toggle

I have a HTML markup close to this:

```
<ul class="menu">
   <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- some other elements and containers here -->

<div class="content">Content 1</div>
<div class="content">Content 2</div>
<div class="content">Content 3</div>
<div class="content">Content 4</div>
```

Unfortunately, I can't change the markup and I need to create simple toggle functionality. What's the best way of creating something that works like:

> if user clicks first link from "menu" fadeIn() first ".content" on the page,
>
> if user clicks second link from "menu" fadeIn() second ".content" on the page
>
> (...)

? Normally I'd use custom data-attributes, but here I guess I'm going to need to count somehow the divs and links? I'd love this to work for unknown number of divs / links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `index()` and `eq()` with that index:

http://jsfiddle.net/Hq69e/

```
$('.menu a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var idx = $(this).parent().index();    
    $('.content').hide().eq(idx).show();
});
```

---

Here's a little nicer version with fading:

http://jsfiddle.net/Wr6Be/

```
$('.menu a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var idx = $(this).parent().index();   

    $('.content:visible').fadeOut(function() {
        $('.content').eq(idx).fadeIn();
    })

});

$('.content:first').show();
```